# Why would the final part of Biffy Clyro - Bubbles remind me of something much older?

Tags: rock, similar-artists, identify-this-genre, prog-rock

Why would the final part (03:26+) of [Biffy Clyro - Bubbles](https://youtu.be/UxUb9Yzr1sE?t=3m26s) remind me of something much older? It reminds of some composition from progressive rock of 70-ies...

Could anyone name what the composition or the band in general does it resemble?

Thanks!

Comment: This is too vague to be an answer IMO, but it might be interesting...  The "vibe" of that part of the song does remind me of a bunch of songs release quite awhile ago, but not at far back as the 1970's.  The groove and slow build seem similar to bands like The Swirlies and Silversun Pickups.  And the tone and almost "drone" reminds me of Smashing Pumpkins.  So I'm getting more of a 1990's noisy rock vibe, which I love. :)

Comment: @cnamejj it is time for me to revise these :)

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer is the shift in time signature. The entire song up to that point is in 4/4, then they change to playing in 7/4. Less conventional time signatures are very common in progressive rock and metal, the latter of which I’d say this more closely resembles. I don’t really listen to prog metal, so unfortunately I can’t give you much deeper insight as to what particular bands they’re emulating.

The other major change in their playing style is the switch to a groove-based musical idea. This isn’t at all specific to prog, but it helps to set the end apart from the rest of the song as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the change in structure, the solo you're referring to was written and performed by Josh Homme of Queens of the Stone Age, which would definitely mark it off as distinct-sounding from the rest of the track. This fact is well known by fans but I couldn't find a super reliable looking source.

https://www.songfacts.com/facts/biffy-clyro/bubbles